# Firestore rules function, exists work but get doesn't

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an interesting and mind boggling problem when dealing with a function in a set of firestore rules. Here's the code below. Basically the exits call passes but the data isn't found but the document does exist. I've verified numerous time. What is the issue with this? I'm not getting it at all. I've tried using examData and ignoring the examFound too but the get wasn't working. Makes no sense to me.

```
match /test-results/{resultId} {

    function canUpdate() {
        let examFound = exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/exams/$(request.resource.data.examId));
        let examData = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/exams/$(request.resource.data.examId)).data;
        return examFound && examData && examData.uids.includes(request.auth.uid);
    }

    function canCreate() {
        return true; // just for now
    }

    allow list: if true;
    allow read: if true;
    allow create: if canCreate();
    allow delete: if canUpdate();
    allow update: if canUpdate();
}
```

On the TS/JS side all I am doing is

```
addDoc(collection(db, 'test-results'), {
  examId,
  uid,
  grade,
})
```

Tried to use only the get and not the exists but nothing worked

Update

Now I am even more puzzled. I did this just to see and I get a permission error when I'm sending the right payload to addDoc.

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.examId;
```

Comment: Now I am even more puzzled. I did this just to see and I get a permission error when I'm sending the right payload to addDoc.

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.examId;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  This includes your application code that makes the query, and the actual database data you're working with.  We should be able to copy it and run it for ourselves to observe the same result.

Comment: Added the addDoc call. Fairly basic

Comment: We still don't have enough to duplicate.  How about the data you're trying to read in the rules?  You said `get` doesn't work, but you haven't shared with us the location or content of that document.  We also can't see the value of `examId` or the users `uid`, which are very important to understanding how this rule works.  Please edit the question to provide enough data that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Some code I can't share due to NDA. I'll try to figure it out on my own then

Comment: You don't have to share the actual data.  You could manually construct a scenario with fake data and minimal code.  This is very common on Stack Overflow.  It's part of creating a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example), which is a requirement for getting good help here.

Comment: This is useless without some data